# Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body APOLLO-CLIENT

Tags: docker, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I'm using docker network and  try to use apollo-client, apollo-upload(createUploadLink) and I try to sent Barear token in headers  too. the error show up `Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body` 
But if I change my url into real url [ not dockerNetwork everything work fine]

```
export const client = (req) => {
  const uri = http://dockerNetwork:3000
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink(req).concat(createUploadLink({
    uri: uri ',
  });),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
};

 const authLink = req => {
  return setContext(_ => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...req.headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${req.cookies.token)}`,
      },
    };
  });
};
```

How can I fix this error by using docker network

Comment: Not familiar with what language this is or what you're trying to accomplish, but given the error you are getting back, I'll throw out that you maybe need to explicitly specify the method (POST, I assume, if there's a body payload)?

Comment: The apostrophe in line `uri: uri ',` looks out of place

Comment: How does the host name `dockerNetwork` relate to your Docker configuration?  Do you have, for example, a `docker-compose.yml` file you could trim down to a minimum and include in an edit to the question?

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution, first I use

```
"@apollo/client": "3.4.20" 
"apollo-upload-client": "^16.0.0",
```

and I downgrade apollo/client to 3.3.20

```
"@apollo/client": "3.3.20",
```